# How to remotely change iCloud settings on iPhone 5?

Tags: iphone, itunes, icloud, activation-lock

I would like to restore factory settings on my iPhone 5. When I try to do
this via iTunes, the computer tells me that I have to change the iCloud settings on my phone:  deactivate "Find my iPhone".

Unfortunately both buttons are inactive on my phone, so I am not able to get to the settings menu. I am also not able to reboot it. I have tried pressing both of them for a long time to no avail.

Do you have any ideas how to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove it from Find My iPhone via the web

- https://www.icloud.com/#find

At that point, iTunes will be willing to erase the device and/or restore it. You could also use Apple Configurator 2 which has a command line option to wipe devices:

```
cfgutil restore
```